# Why is my script pushed in a iframe is executed in the parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I try to push a script into a iframe.
At least the script is pushed 'somewhere' because it outputs something in the console.
If I open the iframe in the debugger I see it in the document INSIDE the iframe.
So everything looks fine until now.

But when it runs the message is inconsistent with the place of execution.
Its output look like it is runned inside the parent : it finds a #parent that exists only in the parent and it doesn't find the #child that has been pushed in the child.

Sorry I cannot make a working fiddle because of security concerns (communication between parent and iframe)

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
<iframe id="frame"></iframe>
  <script>
  var $frm = $("#frame");
  var $doc = $frm[0].contentWindow ? $frm[0].contentWindow.document : $frm[0].contentDocument;
  var $body = $($doc.body);
  $body.html(''); 
  $body.append("<div id='child' >this isthe child</div>");  
  var $head = $($doc.head);
  $head.append($("<script"+">console.log('location = '+window.location + ' ' + 'isParent:' + $('#parent').length + ' ischild:' + $('#child').length); <\/"+"script>"));  
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This outputs

```
location = file:///tmp/test.html isParent:1 ischild:0
```

I expected

```
location = about:/blank isParent:0 ischild:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because jQuery handles evaluating the script content in `append`, rather than having the browser do it. It does that because when you insert a script via `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML`, the script isn't executed. jQuery ensures that the script *is* executed regardless of how it implements `append`.

If you append the script directly using the DOM, it's executed in the correct document (and fails because `$` is undefined).

To do that, replace:

```
$head.append($("<script"+">console.log('location = '+window.location + ' ' + 'isParent:' + $('#parent').length + ' ischild:' + $('#child').length); <\/"+"script>"));
```

with

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.textContent = "console.log('location = '+window.location + ' ' + 'isParent:' + $('#parent').length + ' ischild:' + $('#child').length);";
$head[0].appendChild(script);
```

Of course, you'll probably want to add jQuery to the `iframe`'s document so `$` is defined. :-) You can use the `load` event on `script` to do that:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.onload = function() {
    script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "console.log('location = '+window.location + ' ' + 'isParent:' + $('#parent').length + ' ischild:' + $('#child').length);";
    $head[0].appendChild(script);
};
script.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js";
$head[0].appendChild(script);
```

With those changes, you get the result you're expecting:

```
location = about:blank isParent:0 ischild:1
```

Comment: In fact I was doing a .append($("<script src='foo.js' ><\/script>") and as I saw this line written in the document of the iframe I didn't think it was created in the parent doc before being moved in the child. I used apppendChild now and it works. Thank you